# How to add columns recursively to FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using `FullCalendar` with this extension: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns/
and actually the result reached is this:

[image]

But what I want is insert the column `Op1 and Op2` through an array, 'cause this that you can see in the image above is a default view setted through code like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            views: 
            {
                'multiColAgendaDay': 
                {
                    'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                    'duration': { days: 1 },
                    'columns': 
                    [
                        { id: 1, name: 'Op1' },
                        { id: 2, name: 'Op2' }
                    ]
                }
            },
            'multiColAgendaWeek': 
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { weeks: 1 },
                'columns': 
                [
                    { id: 1, name: 'Op1' },
                    { id: 2, name: 'Op2' }
                ]
            }
        });
```

I've an array with all the `operator` to insert in the columns:

```
$array = array(
"1" => "Operator1",
"2" => "Operator2",
"3" => "Operator3"
);
```

So the results will be like this:

```
'multiColAgendaDay': 
{
        'type': 'multiColAgenda',
        'duration': { days: 1 },
        'columns': 
            [
                { id: 1, name: 'Operator1' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Operator2' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Operator3' }
            ]
}
```

How I can populate the column through code from an array?